# React : Hide "params" from url with React-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a page that receives a custom `id` from the url and fetch data according to that `id`.

For example:

```
let params = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/profile/" + params.id)
        .then((response) => {
            setUsername(response.data.username);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

The problem is that the parameter is displaying in the url, and I would want to hide it, **how to do so ?**

Existing route that output for example `http://localhost:8000/customize/9`:

```
  <Route path="/customize/:id" component={Home} />
```

**What I would want to have in the url :**

```
http://localhost:8000/customize/
```

Comment: If you don't want the param to be in the URL, why do you put it in the route ?
Remove it from the path like this ```path="/customize"``` no ?

Comment: @Marc Charpentier I want to pass the id to the page so I can load elements according to that id. If there is another alternative to that I will welcome it.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

Using useHistory() and history.push() to hide the param in the URL after you fetched data

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

let params = useParams();
let history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/profile/" + params.id)
        .then((response) => {
            setUsername(response.data.username);
            history.push("/customize");
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);
```

And here add a `?` after the `:id` to specify that's an optional parameter that can be there or not

```
<Route path="/customize/:id?" component={Home} />
```

Comment: Nice, unfortunately your id will still be in the url until the data is fetched correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the id from route params if you don't need it this way. And then pass the id to the component in a different way like as a prop to the component.

```
<Route path="/customize" render={() => <Home id={9} />} />
```